# how to get the current order of all columns (visible or invisible) in dataTables after using colReorder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have a table populated with dataTabels jquery plugin.
after i use colReorder plugin on it and reorder my columns,
how can i get all my collumns order.
let me explain little more.
if i have all my columns visible it is fairly easy. but when i make some columns disapear with colViz plugin of dataTables it destroy the whole column and its not there for me to get any thing of it.
the problem is that i know that the order is present somewhere in the oTable object, because when you change the order of columns in your table with colReorder in colViz list the order changes and it containes all my columns names.
i searched all three of js files thoroughly. but could not found any thing helpfull.
though i can not use the colVix button names, because they are not present in page and after i click on show/hide columns list they are generated. in addition i can not trigger a click on it because it has a fairly long animation that make it almost impossible to use this cheap tricks on it.
can any one help?

**EDIT:**
i think it is clear:
i just want a list with titles of my columns visible or hidden especially after using reorder

Comment: Really not clear what you need. Very hard to understand explanation of buttons.

Comment: plz tell me which part is unclear?

Comment: most of question is unclear. What do you need from hidden columns and what needs to trigger the seacrh

Comment: dear @charlietfl i edited my question plz taje a look thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `colVis` button clicks  to create array based on checkboxes checked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ColVis_Button:not(.ColVis_MasterButton)',function(){
     var colsArray= $('.ColVis_Button :checkbox').map(function(){
      return [[$(this).parent().next('.ColVis_title').text(), this.checked ? 'visibile':'hidden']];
    }).get();
    console.log(colsArray)

});
```